# Flutter get json data and send to printer

Tags: flutter, dart

this is a simple app for queue ticket dispenser (we use Sunmi T2mini for that purpose) which sends data to local API and gets created queue data from it. after that ticket is printing
i'm a bit new in Flutter and can't figure out what am i doing wrong

here's my code:

```
class requestTicket extends StatefulWidget {
  final int srvid;
  const requestTicket({Key? key, required this.srvid}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<requestTicket> createState() => _requestTicketState(srvid);
}
class _requestTicketState extends State<requestTicket> {
  int srvid;
  List data;
  String Queue = '';
  String BranchTitle = '';
  String ServiceTitle = '';
  String Created = '';

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
    initBindPrinter();
  }
  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await SunmiFlutterPrint.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;
  }

  initBindPrinter() async {
    await SunmiFlutterPrint.bindPrinter();
  }
  _requestTicketState(this.srvid) {
    fetchTicket();
    new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()));
      });
    });
  }
  Future<List<Ticket>> fetchTicket() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(APIURL+'create_queue/$srvid'));
    var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
      data = convertDataToJson['Tickets'];
    });
    return (responseJson['Tickets'] as List)
        .map((p) => Ticket.fromJson(p))
        .toList();
  }

  void printTicketToSunmi(Queue,BranchTitle,ServiceTitle,Created) async {
    SunmiFlutterPrint.setLineWrap(line: 1);
    SunmiFlutterPrint.setAlignment(align : TEXTALIGN.CENTER);
    SunmiFlutterPrint.printTextWithFont(text: 'təşəkkür edirik!', fontName: 'ShapeRegular', fontSize: 25);
    SunmiFlutterPrint.setLineWrap(line: 3);
    SunmiFlutterPrint.autoOutPaper();
    SunmiFlutterPrint.unbindPrinter();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        printTicketToSunmi(Queue,BranchTitle,ServiceTitle,Created);
        body:SafeArea(
          child: Center(

              child: Text('TƏŞƏKKÜR EDİRİK!',textAlign: TextAlign.center,style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white,fontFamily: "ShapeBold",fontSize: 40))
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}

class Ticket {
  final String queue;
  final String created;
  final String branch_title;
  final String service_title;
  Ticket({this.queue,this.created,this.branch_title,this.service_title});
  factory Ticket.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Ticket(
        queue: json['queue'],
        created: json['created'],
        branch_title: json['branch_title'],
        service_title: json['service_title']
    );
  }
}
```

and these are errors i got:

```
LINE 38: Non-nullable instance field 'data' must be initialized.

LINE 71: Positional arguments must occur before named arguments.

LINE 87: The parameter 'queue' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
LINE 87: The parameter 'created' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
LINE 87: The parameter 'branch_title' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
LINE 87: The parameter 'service_title' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
```

any advices please?

Comment: The errors have very verbose messages that *should* enable you to fix them. I don't see any merit in paraphrasing a perfectly fine english sentence to you. Can you explain what exactly you don't understand about these messages? What did you try to fix them and where are you stuck?

Comment: Also, you should not make StackOverflow questions with multiple entire seperate questions but instead focus on a specific problem and get an answer for that problem. Each of your errors are really not related to each other.

Comment: Matter of fact, none of them have anything to do with json data or a printer. Each is a very basic Dart syntax error.

Comment: @nvoigt sorry maybe my English is not good enough. I can't understand what means "Non-nullable instance field 'data' must be initialized."
i mean i think i'm initializing it with "List data;"

Comment: @julemand101 those are not multiple questions but multiple errors which i can't figure out. The question is how to send data to API and then Print it's response.

Comment: @nvoigt agree with you regarding syntax errors. Can you help with fixing them?

Comment: @PhAbd You are asking to get help on fixing the errors you are getting. Each of these errors can be asked in separate issues since they are not related to each other. You should also be able to search on each error and find multiple answers on how to fix them since they are very common and have already been asked before.

Comment: @julemand101 thanks for advices, but I don't get errors when i separate my code to pieces. only when trying to put them together in one application

Comment: @PhAbd What does the line `printTicketToSunmi(Queue,BranchTitle,ServiceTitle,Created);` do inside the `Scaffold` you are creating? That is not even close to valid Dart system and looks like you have pasted something into your code by accident.

Comment: @PhAbd A problem not related to this question. Your code does not follow the recommended style guide for naming things. Please always start class names with big casing and variables (and methods) with small casing.

Comment: @PhAbd Your `Ticket` class is not made with Dart null-safety in mind. Please add the keyword `required` to each parameter in the constructor like: `Ticket({required this.queue,required this.created,required this.branch_title,required this.service_title});`. You can read this for why this is needed: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters

Comment: @julemand101 thanks for that. tried but the result is the same. I will now follow your advice and recheck my code fully. thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241418/discussion-between-julemand101-and-ph-abd).